# AWS Lambda: Can't access event['param'] via URL but it works on API GW Test

Tags: aws-lambda

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(event['param'])
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I succesfully setup API Gateway, a Python Lambda Function, proper DNS via Route53 and a valid TLS cert...

I can access my Lambda via calling mydomain.com/lambda but I'm not getting any params to pass through, only this error. Been trying for 5 frustrating hours now.

**When called via mydomain.com/lambda**

```
 errorMessage   "'param'"
    errorType   "KeyError"
    stackTrace  
    0   "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    \"body\": json.dumps(event['param'])\n"
```

**When called via API Gateway's "Test" (all good here)**

```
    Execution log for request 
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request:
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {}
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: 
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=Authorization=...[TRUNCATED]
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
    {
      "param" : "foo"
    }
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Sending request to 
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 36 ms
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response headers: [...]
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Successfully completed execution
    Tue Nov 05 22:42:47 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 200
```

And finally success (via API Gateway's "Test")

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "\"foo\""
}
```

How to get it working via URL? I try to actually get some header params from the client (browser) but step-by-step to learn. Seems I cannot even get anything to pass through from API Gateway to Lambda when called via URL, but why? What am I not getting here conceptually? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set it all up correctly but didn't know that I had to re-deploy the API to make changes happen publicly.

That was the answer: Deploy the API again.